# HSQLDB 2.3.3: How to create type array

Tags: hsqldb

How do I create an array of type BIGINT?

The following does not seem to work:

```
create TYPE ARRAY_NUMBERS AS ARRAY OF BIGINT;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TYPE ARRAY_NUMBERS AS BIGINT ARRAY;
```